# Hard drive not recognized by usb 3.0 ports

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

I have storejet 1000GB with usb 3.0 connection but it seems that in my laptop runs windows 7, the computer identifies it only when connecting it to the usb 2 port. There was period it was identified in one of the usb 3.0 ports but now in allof my 3.0 ports its not recognized.
what can I do? i have there a lot of data (around 600GB full)

Comment: have you installed the latest USB 3.0 drivers for your laptop?

Comment: The hdd had been working fine since june but around july one 3.0 port stopped working with the hdd and now also the other one. Drivers are indeed installed. Maybe I need to reinstall them ? I have dell vostro 3550.

Comment: yes, try to reinstall the driver. Also try to remove the USB controller from the device manager, reboot and let Windows reinstall the driver.